# Mixed Authentication in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, iis, ldap

I am developing an ASP.NET application which works inside both Internal and External networks.

For Internal networks, I want to use Windows Authentication. And Forms Authentication for External networks.

Which means, If the user/computer belongs to the domain, it's logged in without asking any credentials, and fall-back page will be a login form which asks username and password for users stored in SQL.

I have done forms authentication using Directory Services against LDAP. But, It's not integrated. Even the domain user has to type the credentials again.

Is there any Idea to get authenticated using current System User details, or Mixed Authentication.